# SQL query for removing non-unique row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using postgreSQL 9.2.

Let I've the following table:

```
  id       name           definition
serial   varchar(128)        text
  1        name1           definition1
..........................................
```

I need to write a query that remove all rows with the same name such that every row will have unique name. If two rows have the same name, their definitions are also the same.

Comment: You want to actually delete these row?  How do you know which one to keep?  What if a given name has multiple definitions?

Comment: Yes, I do. Such rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use row_number() function on name and remove all rows that have row_number() > 1

Here is an example query: [Deleting duplicates](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Deleting_duplicates)

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM mytable dd
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT *
   FROM mytable ex
   WHERE ex.name = dd.name
   AND ex.id < dd.id
   );
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you even let client applications to add rows when name duplicates in the first place?